# I just installed 12.04, and all of the text on the screen is displaying the incorrect characters. Would anyone know how to fix that?

Tags: 12.04, display, text

I wish I could post an image, but I'll try to describe my issue. All of the text (except within applications) looks to be scrambled or switching characters.

Answer (score 1):

you seem has got wrong keyboard layout while you were setting keyboard layout in installation setup session.

to fix it :

1. go to system settings > keyboard layout
2. delete current keyboard layout by clicking **-** button.
3. add new keyboard layout by clicking **+** button
4. choose based on your country and your keyboard layout and finally click **add** button